# Laravel Request Concurrency without queues

Tags: php, laravel, xmlhttprequest

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    sleep(10);
    return 'Test!';
});
```

Calling this request from an asynchronous loop javascript would result the requests in a sequential manner. Laravel version is 5.6 with default configurations. Your help is admired achieving concurrency here.

Answer (score 0):

Was using php artisan serve and reverse proxy to redirect requests. Adding a virtual server config entry to the public directory of the laravel project solved the issue.